# Escaping special characters in Ballerina

Tags: enums, escaping, identifier, ballerina

I need to define a `MembershipStatus` Enum as depicted below.

```
public enum MembershipStatus {
    INVITED,
    REGISTERED, 
    DEACTIVATED, 
    RE-INVITED
}
```

It says operator `'-' not defined for 'string'`. What is the correct way of specifying `RE-INVITED`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape with the character `\`, something like this
`RE\-INVITED`